# Javascript Beginner Question / what is the problem in those codes in making to do list?

Tags: javascript

I am making to do list following the video. Then mine works not good even although my codes and teacher's codes are same. Problem is the filtering should happen when it click select option on select window(?) like image1. However it dosent work and after click the option "done" and when click the select button, it works only then image 2. What is the problem? I want to show the checked lists when it is clicked on image1, not image2 ... please help me.

(the codes are edited in filtering part for looking better)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MO63p.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOSWd.png)

```js
const todoInput = document.querySelector(".todo-input")
const todoPlusBtn = document.querySelector(".todo-button")
const todoUl = document.querySelector(".todo-list")
const todoFilter = document.querySelector(".filter-todo")

//event listeners
todoPlusBtn.addEventListener('click', addTodo);
todoUl.addEventListener('click', delTodo);
todoFilter.addEventListener('click', filterTodo);


function filterTodo (click){
    const div = todoUl.childNodes;
        div.forEach(function(todo){
        switch(click.target.value){
            case "ALL":
                todo.style.dispaly = 'flex';
                break;
            case "DONE":
                if(todo.classList.contains('completed')){
                    todo.style.display = 'flex';
                } else{
                    todo.style.display = 'none';
                }
            break;
            case "TO DO":
                if(!todo.classList.contains('completed')){
                    todo.style.display = 'flex';
                } else{
                    todo.style.display = 'none';
                }
            break;
        }
    });
```